# Append one of three data attributes to element but replace what is already appended

Tags: jquery, append

I have a div table containing multiple choices with three options each like so:

```
| question 1 | option 1 | option 2 | option 3 |
| question 2 | option 1 | option 2 | option 3 |
| question 3 | option 1 | option 2 | option 3 |
```

and so on ...

Every option is in a `<div>` with data attribute .. lets say "data-opt".
What I am trying to do is to append the data attribute "data-opt" to another div onclick, but I also need to replace what is already appended if the user makes change to what he has chosen. For example a user clicks "option 1" on "question 1" but then he decides to change his choice with "option 2".
Another scenario - The user answers "question 1" with "option 1", "question 2" with "option 2" and "question 3" with "option 3" but then he changes the answer to "question 1" with "option 3" - I want to change only the answer for "question 1" and keep all other answers.

What I've been able to achieve already is to append an answer only once but I have no Idea how to change the user choice if he makes changes...

I think I can actually achieve it but I want to keep it as simple as possible and as I am not so familiar with jquery I will have to write couple of functions and my code will become a mess.

Thats what I've already:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).one('click',function(event){
    choice = $(event.target).data('opt');
    $('#another').append(choice);

});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8vpm1gck/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('body').on('click','.cell',function(event){
        choice = $(this).data('opt');
        if($('div[data-question="'+$(this).parent().index()+'"]').length == 0)
        $('#another').append('<div data-question="'+$(this).parent().index()+'">'+choice+'</div>');
        else {
        $('div[data-question="'+$(this).parent().index()+'"]').text(choice);
        }

});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/771L1zaa/

Comment: Thanks alot. That exactly what I needed. One more question. Do I need to use    .html() instead of     .text() in order to have an html element inside the appended div when a user changes his choice ?

Comment: if user is changing his choice we have the appended html we just change the text in it,you can remove the previous value+html and append a new html if you like